# Invalid Datatype trying to alter table

Tags: sql, oracle, types

I got a table which I used the below code to create.

```
create table Meter (MeterID CHAR(8) CONSTRAINT MeterPK PRIMARY KEY,
                Value CHAR(8) CONSTRAINT ValueNN NOT NULL,
                InstalledDate Date CONSTRAINT InDateNN NOT NULL);
```

Then I tried adding a derived column that adds 6 months to the installeddate.

```
alter table meter add ExpiryDate as (add_months(installedDate,6)) not null;
```

This returns an error of invalid datatype.

I read somewhere that I do not have to specify the datatype of ExpiryDate as it can be derived from the function. So where did I go wrong?

EDIT: Turns out Mike was right. I used the trigger method to get things going, but I was confused whether I'm using mysql or oracle. Think in the end I'm using oracle actually. Have problems with the trigger but turns out I do not need to have the command "set" in the trigger. Below is the code that works.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER trigexpdate1
BEFORE INSERT ON Meter
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.ExpiryDate := ADD_MONTHS(:NEW.InstalledDate, 6);
END;
```

If I don't have the begin and end in the statement, it will throw an error saying illegal trigger specification.

Comment: Is it mysql or oracle?

Comment: Why can't use view instead of adding computed column to the table.

Comment: That looks more like Oracle syntax. Where in the MySQL manual did you find a hint that this would be working for MySQL?

Comment: Sorry about it. I was mistaken about me using mysql. I'm using Oracle instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support

- derived columns in table definitions,
- a function named `add_months()`, or
- inline constraints.

This is a more or less standard way to write that statement in MySQL.

```
create table `Meter` (
  `MeterID` CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `Value` CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `InstalledDate` Date NOT NULL,
  primary key (`MeterID`)
);
```

You have two options for a derived column like "ExpiryDate".

1. Create a view, and do the date arithmetic in the view. Use [date_add()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).
2. Add the column "ExpiryDate" to the table, and keep it up-to-date with a trigger.

---

**BEFORE INSERT trigger example**

```
create table `Meter` (
  `MeterID` CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `Value` CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `InstalledDate` Date NOT NULL,
  `ExpiryDate` Date not null,
  primary key (`MeterID`)
);

create trigger trigexpdate1 
before insert on `Meter` 
FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.`ExpiryDate` = date_add(NEW.`InstalledDate`, interval 6 month);
```

Note how ExpiryDate changes from the insert statement to the select statement below.

```
insert into Meter 
values ('1', '1', '2014-07-01', '2014-07-01');

select * from Meter;
```

```
MeterID  Value  InstalledDate  ExpiryDate
--
1        1      2014-07-01     2015-01-01
```

Comment: Tried the trigger method with this code.

create trigger trigexpdate1 AFTER INSERT on Meter FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
update meter SET ExpiryDate = installeddate;
END;

This is to test if my trigger code is working so I tried to duplicate the value in installeddate over to expirydate.

After this, I tried inserting values into the table but I got the error.

METER is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

As I understand it, it's because my trigger is also updating the column as the insert is doing it. But how do I overcome this problem?

Comment: You need a `before insert` trigger, not an `after insert` trigger. (You need a `before update` trigger, too.) And you should change the values of NEW.ExpiryDate. Read through the [trigger examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Comment: No can do. Still unable to get it. Tried create trigger trigexpdate1 BEFORE INSERT on Meter FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

update meter SET NEW.EXPIRYDATE = to_date('2002-12-11', 'yyyy-mm-dd') ;
END;

And I get an Error(3,18): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NEW"."EXPIRYDATE": invalid identifier.

Comment: OK. After more research, it seems that I have to use :NEW to refer to the column. It compiles with no error after that. But after i insert values into the table, the trigger did not seem to have activate. Here's my insert command.

insert into meter values (1000, 200000,to_date('2008-11-11', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2008-12-11', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), '','aaa','');

Comment: @WangMingKang: Added a working trigger example.

Comment: Currently, I'm having the invalid character error trying to compile your trigger example. Sorry about it but I'm a total newbie to mysql.

Comment: Hmmm, I seem to have gotten rid of the invalid character error by doing this.

create trigger trigexpdate1 
before insert on Meter 
FOR EACH ROW 
begin
  SET NEW.ExpiryDate = date_add(NEW.InstalledDate, interval 6 month);
  end;

Now I got the compiling error of missing or invalid option.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: It's ok now. I have solved the problem. Turns out I'm not using mysql after all but Oracle. Sorry for the big misunderstanding and thanks for your help.